# Open Itunes from iphone application

Tags: iphone, app-store, itunes

I want to open iTunes with a button click from the application to download an iTunes video. What link I should give for this?

Comment: Not sure if this helps.. but u can have a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7316646/942966

Comment: thanks for your comment, but it does not work, it only returns json, i want to open itunes...

Comment: and in the JSON there is value for "trackViewUrl". Can that URL help ? Did you check that ?

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a iTunes Link Maker tool that you can use to generate the links

[More information here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/iTunesLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007896-SW1)

With the link, you can then use

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:itunesURL];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [iTunes Link Maker](http://iTunesLinkMaker.com) and **remove the country code** (i.e. "**us**") out of the link and it would always work open iTunes always and not a browser on the way (if there is iTunes installed on the target system).

Then use the link you got to replace THE_ITUNES_LINK on your code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:THE_ITUNES_LINK];
```