# How to get documentation or reference list of Apple's iTunes web objects services

Tags: web-services, itunes, webobjects

Apple's Search API doesn't provide me all the information I need. I saw from this post that [How can I fetch information about the app/song/video etc. from iTunes Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460364/how-can-i-fetch-information-about-the-app-song-video-etc-from-itunes-store) that there is a web service (e.g. http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=$appID&mt=8).

After searching for a while, I can see that there are other similar services from Apple e.g.

- https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewGrouping?cc=us&id=29520&mt=12
- http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/wa/wsSearch?
- etc

Is there anywhere a listing (e.g. a WSDL) or document that specifies the web services that are available?